# Excel JS Add-In with IE11 - Dialog API stops execution of code until you open F12Chooser or IEChooser

Tags: office-js, office-js-helpers, excel-web-addins

I have an Excel JS Add-In where I am leveraging Dialog API with the `displayDialogAsync` method. With Edge, it works perfectly and the handler gets triggered and the code runs fine. But if the add-in is loaded in IE11 browser IFrame, the dialog stays open and the handler does not complete execution unless I open IEChooser.exe from F12 folder. As soon as I open, the code gets executed like normal!

I used to work on IE11 and there is a commonly known issue that sometimes any `console.log` messages can stop execution of code because of non-instantiation of the `console` object in IE11. Problem is, I have removed all logging from my add-in but the issue still persists. The only `console.log` that are present is by the office.js library itself, but it still fails to load until I open IEChooser.exe.

Our app is not working in production due to this and I am out of ideas.

Comment: This seems to be a bug. I think you should create an issue on the [office-js](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues) repo.

Comment: I have already done that. Waiting on them to respond, in the meantime I thought I'd check with stackoverflow if someone faced a similar issue.

Comment: @RickKirkham can you possibly help me get in touch with someone on the Office JS API dev team? The github issue I raised almost a month ago doesn't seem to be garnering attention despite repeated comments: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/1699

Comment: I'm trying to get some attention to this issue internally.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am doing additional debugging by myself but because there is no point adding console.log (because the issue doesn't occur if console is open) I am finding it very hard to narrow down to the issue. I believe it might be related to the dialog object not properly being handled but I cannot be sure 100%.

Comment: Your office-js repo issue was closed. If you are still having difficulty with the original issue, please add a comment to it asking that it be reopened.